# I need to change the colour of the workspace in Code::Blocks

Tags: codeblocks

[image]

I installed a dark theme for code::blocks but the workspace light theme annoys me, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Configure desktop -> Appearance->Application Style- GNOME Application Style (GTK)
Select GTK2 Theme: Breeze-Dark
Select GTK3 Theme: Breeze-Dark